# Terminal automatically entering input from program as a command

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, nasm

I am trying to teach myself how to write Assembly in X86 on NASM. I'm attempting to write a program that takes a single integer value and prints it back to standard output before exiting.

My code:

```
section .data
        prompt: db "Enter a number: ", 0
        str_length: equ $ - prompt

section .bss
        the_number: resw 1

section .text

global _start

_start:
        mov eax, 4      ; pass sys_write
        mov ebx, 1      ; pass stdout
        mov edx, str_length     ; pass number of bytes for prompt
        mov ecx, prompt     ; pass prompt string
        int 80h
        
        mov eax, 3      ; sys_read
        mov ebx, 0      ; stdin
        mov edx, 1      ; number of bytes
        mov ecx, [the_number]       ; pass input of the_number
        int 80h
        
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov edx, 1
        mov ecx, [the_number]
        int 80h
        
        mov eax, 1          ; exit
        mov ebx, 0          ; status 0
        int 80h
```

From there I do the assembling `nasm -felf -o input.o input.asm` and linking `ld -m elf_i386 -o input input.o`.

I run a test and input an integer and when I press enter, the program exits and Bash tries to execute the number input as a command. I even `echo`'d the exit status and been returned with 0.

So this is an odd behavior.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but your prompt shouldn’t have a null byte after it, since you pass the length to the system call. You’re writing the null byte to the output device, which could have a weird effect, depending on the output device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to read fails and doesn’t read any input.  When your program exits, that input is still waiting to be read on the TTY (which was this program's stdin), at which point bash reads it.

You should check the return status of your system calls. If EAX is a negative number when the system call returns, it is the error code. For example, in this case, EAX contains -14, which is EFAULT (“Bad address”).

The reason read fails is that you are passing an invalid pointer as the buffer address. You need to load the address of `the_number`, not its value. Use `mov ecx, the_number`.

Comment: The write system call also needs the address of the buffer, not the contents.

Comment: It’s actually very surprising to me that the read system call waits for input before checking the validity of the `buf` parameter. I had to write a test program to confirm that before writing this answer.

Comment: I expect this is because the check is done automatically when the data is copied into user space, so doing an additional check beforehand would be redundant, and slow down the normal case where the address is valid.

Comment: It is now somewhat solved. I took the content value out and made it the address instead for both the read and final write calls. I also changed `resw` to 4.

Comment: @Nate, yeah I was thinking that, but it has to cook the input before it is ready to write to the buffer, but then it leaves the input unread, which confused me. I finally realized that it cooks the input into yet another kernel buffer before copying it to user space, so it’s easy for it to leave it unread in the cooked buffer.